# Need help to come up with regex to turn this into a link

Tags: php, regex

I need to turn the following into a link:

> <a
>   href="http://maps.google.com/maps?um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=little+river+canyon+center&fb=1&gl=us&hq=little+river+canyon+center&hnear=0x888a614b2e7272e5%3A0x913a5fafeec714d6%2CCentre%2C+AL&ei=GBsFTtedF8vUgAfex6zNAQ&sa=X&oi=local_group&ct=image&ved=0CAQQtgM<br" target="_blank">http://maps.google.com/maps?um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=little+river+canyon+center&fb=1&gl=us&hq=little+river+canyon+center&hnear=0x888a614b2e7272e5%3A0x913a5fafeec714d6%2CCentre%2C+AL&ei=GBsFTtedF8vUgAfex6zNAQ&sa=X&oi=local_group&ct=image&ved=0CAQQtgM<br</a>
>   />

Here is the regex I currently use that doesn't work:

```
$hike_description = preg_replace('#([\s|^])(www)#i', '$1http://$2', $hike_description);
$pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^<\s]+)#i';
$replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
$hike_description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $hike_description);
```

Hike description is the text I need to make into a link.

Comment: NOTE!!!!!!  The html I posted that I need to convert isn't appearing as I posted it.  Please look at it from the "edit" screen.

Comment: is this part of another string? might be taking the wrong aproach

Comment: Yeah its part of a bigger string, but this is the piece that is causing the problem.  Try to edit my post and you will see the real html there.  It is an evil snippet.  The html that renders in my question isn't actually it.

Comment: @Genadinik You just needed to use `&lt;` instead of `<`

Comment: @Genadinik Please confirm that the current text is correct. If it isn't please revert my edit.

Comment: Uhm... unless I am mistaken, the html you posted already is a link. Turning it into one seems unnecessary.

Comment: @cwallenpoole  yes that is correct!

Comment: @Jens it is a link which does not end.  Look at what it does to the middle and bottom of this page: http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=209

Comment: @Ibu THis is not supposed to look correct. It is broken. That's the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edited question this is not really clear any more, but from the original one I guess that the whole problem here is that the link ends with `<br`, which is not legal in HTML.

Try using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on the $hike_description.

Comment: Should I apply the specialchars before or after I try to perform the regex on the string?

Answer (score 1):

try trimming first the "/>"

```
 $hike_description="http://maps.google.com/maps?um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=little+river+canyon+center&fb=1&gl=us&hq=little+river+canyon+center&hnear=0x888a614b2e7272e5%3A0x913a5fafeec714d6%2CCentre%2C+AL&ei=GBsFTtedF8vUgAfex6zNAQ&sa=X&oi=local_group&ct=image&ved=0CAQQtgM />";

$hike_description =trim($hike_description,"/>");


$hike_description = preg_replace('#([\s|^])(www)#i', '$1http://$2', $hike_description);
$pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^<\s]+)#i';

$replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
$hike_description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $hike_description);
```

Comment: The text I posted is part of a bigger text so cutting off a piece of it wouldn't help me here.  I need a more general solution :(

Comment: is the "/>" originally part of the bigger text? And  does this bigger text vary?